# Looking for a smart map

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference-counting

I have a global map to store smartpointers.
Other classes getting these pointers by key.

They have the using key as member variabel: int USING_POINTER_KEY.

So I can define in "getGlobalPointer": getting the pointer from map by key 'USING_POINTER_KEY'.

It works! And I got enough reasons to store my pointers in this way. It's ok.

My problem is: How can I teach my global map to remove automatically entries which no longer used by classes?

I think with reference-counting. But I am not sure how...

Comment: Let's say your map is a site full of videos, like, you know, that tube site. People come and retrieve videos by key, watch them a bit, then continue with their lives. You want to remove videos that are no longer used. What does it mean exactly? Videos that no one watches at the moment? I don't think your customers will be happy. Videos that no one will ever watch? How do you know what people will do?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of catch-all scheme is a red flag.

But, you can create a custom deleter with the smart pointer (`std::shared_ptr`). Just pass the function pointer as the second argument to the `shared_ptr` constructor. The function can remove the pointer from the global table.

Smart pointers are already an implementation of reference counting, so you just want to add a callback.

Comment: If a `shared_ptr` is kept in the map, the reference count won't be 0. So you should put a `std::weak_ptr` there.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl Yeah, I should have mentioned that. The class should be derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. The first `shared_ptr` to represent an actual client gets the deleter passed to its constructor.